# rails average query return an interval instead of big decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have query:

```
MyModel.includes(:line_items).where("line_items.is_deleted = ?", false).where("line_items.is_verified = ?", false).references(:line_items).average("age(line_items.created_at)")
```

And I am trying to get the avg amount of time these `line_item` records have been in the database with the `average("age(line_items.created_at)")` piece. This is returning a BigDecimal which I dont know what to do with, is there any way to have it return an interval?

Comment: What do you mean by "interval"?

Comment: @nicholas79171 there is a return type in Postgres called interval. If I run the same query in pgadmin I get an interval returned

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to return an `ActiveSupport::Duration` from a Postgresql interval column, bu you're not getting an ISO 8601 interval back here, I suspect, because `average` expects a numeric response. You probably want to call `.seconds` on the result to turn it into an `ActiveSupport::Duration`:

```
average_age = MyModel.average('age(line_items.created_at)')
average_age.seconds.class #=> ActiveSupport::Duration
```